# How can I target a specific chunk of days, after a specific date, in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm using the below formula to display an expiration warning after 25 days have passed. However, the warning persists after 30 days... I don't want to see the warning text "Expiration Warning" after 30 days. How can I make it so I only see the warning between days 25 and 30, after whatever date is in cell B2?

```
=IF(AND($B2 <= (TODAY() - 25), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("30 Days", A2))), """Expiration Warning""", "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

=IF(ISBETWEEN(TODAY(),B2+25,B2+30),"Expiration Warning",)

Comment: =IF(AND($B2 <= (TODAY()B2+25,B2+30), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text of interest", A2))), """Expiration Warning""", "")

Formula parse error... also the text of interest is necessary

Comment: =IF(AND(ISBETWEEN(TODAY(), I768+25,I768+30), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text", E768))), """Expiration Warning""", "") works. thank you!